# Implements complex operator+(double,complex) as a member function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, member-functions

I've read the section **13.5** of the working draft N3797 and I've one question. Let `complex` be a class type which represents complex numbers. We can define the following operator function:

```
complex operator+(double d, complex c)
{
    return *new complex(d+c.get_real(),c.get_imagine());
}
```

But how this operator function can be implements as a complex member function? Or must I to declare this operator function in every module which I've intend to use them?

Comment: you are leaking memory. and it can't be member function

Comment: In all but the rarest of circumstances (and this isn't an exception) you can bet your bottom dollar if you *ever* see `*new Something...` you're leaking memory like a sieve leaks rain water.

Comment: @BryanChen Where is leaking? And how to avoid it?

Comment: Don't call `new`, that is how to avoid it. You have no reason to do so anyway.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is this:

```
inline complex operator +(double d, const complex& c)
{
    return complex(d+c.get_real(), c.get_imagine());
}
```

This cannot be a member function if you want the operator to handle a left-side of the operator as a `double`. It must be a free function, possibly friended if access to anything besides the public interface of `complex` is needed.

If you want the *right* side of the add-op to be a `double`, a member function *can* be crafted:

```
complex operator +(double d) const
{
    return complex(d+get_real(), get_imagine());
}
```

Note this is assuming this definition is within the body of the `complex` class definition. But in the interest of clarity I would recommend *both* be inline free functions.

---

**Implicit Construction**

Lined up with the usual suspects, what you're at-least-appearing to try to do is generally done with an implicit conversion constructor and a general free-function. By providing this:

```
complex(double d) : real(d), imagine() 
{
}
```

in the class definition a double can implicitly construct a temporary `complex` where needed. This allows this:

```
inline complex operator +(const complex& lhs, const complex& rhs)
{
    return complex(lhs.get_real() + rhs.get_real(), 
                   lhs.get_imagine() + rhs.get_imagine());
}
```

to be used as a general solution to all sensible manifestations of what you appear to want.

Comment: Might be worth adding that the usual approach is to provide an implicit converting constructor from `double`, and provide only one overload `complex operator+(const complex&, const complex&);`. This allows double + complex, complex + double and complex + compex.

Comment: @juanchopanza absolutely. The why-this-doesn't-work was the focus, but your note well-worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to define a binary operator overload, such as the binary + operator, between two types.

1. As a member function.

   When you define it as member function, the LHS of the operator is an instance of the class. The RHS of the operator is the argument to the function. That's why when you define it as member function, it can only have one argument.
2. As a free function.

   These functions must have two arguments. The first argument is the LHS of the operator and the second argument is the RHS of the operator.

Since `double` is not a class, you have to define operator+ overload between `double` as LHS and `complex` as RHS as a free function, with `double const&` or `double` as the first argument type and `complex const&` or `complex` as the second argument type.

Comment: Usually what is done is to provide an implicit converting constructor from `double`, then you only need one operator overload.

Comment: @juanchopanza: ...which still has to be defined as a free function, because implicit conversions are not applied to method invocant.

Comment: @JanHudec Of course, I didn't mean to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @juanchopanza: But since the question includes "... as a member function" I feel it is important to state that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, operator overloading requires class types. You cannot overload the `+` operator for the basic type `double`.

Also, except in certain circumstances (short-lived programs or throwaway code), the pointer resulting from a call to the `new` operator should be captured, so that it can be later released with `delete`, preventing a situation known as a memory leak.

Comment: remark: An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or be a non-member function and have at least one parameter whose type is a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an enumeration. Hence I can overload + operator which LHS is double and RHS is reference to class.

Comment: The right hand operand of that operator is a class type, so the requirement is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

For it to be a member, the first parameter must be of the **class type**(though it is not explicitly specified). But you are sending a `double` as first argument. If you need this to work either make it `friend` function or just `non-member` function which can work only using `public interface` of the `Complex` class. And as others pointed out, you are leaking memory.